# Laravel error handling, get_class vs instanceof

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-exceptions

In the following code in app/Exceptions/Handler.php, the first one doesn't work but the second one does.

`dd(get_class($exception));` outputs "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException".

The first one is [similar to the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#render-method). How can I make it work using `instanceof`?

```
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        //dd(get_class($exception));
        // this does not work.
        if ($exception instanceof Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException
) {
            return response()->json(['error'=>['message'=>'Resouce not found']], 404);
        }
        // This one works.
        if(get_class($exception) == "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException") {
            return response()->json(['error'=>['message'=>'Resouce not found']], 404);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Comment: Try to add \ like this : `if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException) { //... }` and see if it will work !

Comment: No it doesn't work either.

Comment: try to add `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException as ModelNotFoundException;` on top an then `if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) { //... }`

Comment: Yes, it worked. Can you put this in the answer so that I can tick it as a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use `instanceof` you must use the full class name, and if your class has a namespace then you should use the fully qualified class name of the class.

And there is an other way to use `instanceof` using a short name (alias) for a given class thanks to `use` statement, in your case you can use it like so :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException as ModelNotFoundException; // on top of course :) 

if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>['message'=>'Resouce not found']], 404);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes an $exception is rethrown, so try to use

```
$exception->getPrevious() instanceof XXX
```

or

```
get_class($exception->getPrevious()) == 'XXX'
```